# Any ideas how to get a parallax effect in a single wordpress article?

Tags: jquery, wordpress, parallax

Is it possible to combine the parallax scrolling effect on a single wordpress article or wordpress page? Something like a custom post type combined with a jquery-plugin ...

I know, there are solutions for a background image by wp-justParallax.js (http://codecanyon.net/item/wpjustparallax-a-parallax-plugin-for-wordpress/full_screen_preview/5163957). But is it possible to have the effect, e.g. on a banner on top of the title and the content of a website using wordpress as a cms?

I doubt that there is a plugin-solution, but well ... I don't give up hope ;)

Any suggestions how to start doing this?

Have you already tried it and – in the best case – made it to work?

Thanks for your help!

Best, cutterkom

P.S. The topic was already discussed on css-tricks, without success http://css-tricks.com/forums/topic/free-wordpress-plugin-for-parallax-scrolling/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this out, very simple tutorial to achieve the same effect:

[check it here](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/simple-parallax-scrolling-technique/)

P.S: if you want to target a specific page in WP, take a look at the source code of the page and you will find a unique body ID. Use that ID to create the effect for that specific page.

Comment: Thanks. I am going to try that!

Answer (score 0):

kindly have look at here,

the simple plugin will works like you want check it here [Codecanyon-wp-justParallax](http://codecanyon.net/item/wpjustparallax-a-parallax-plugin-for-wordpress/5163957)

Comment: I know this plugin (see my post), it works only for backgrounds.

Answer (score 0):

The plugin http://codecanyon.net/item/wpjustparallax-a-parallax-plugin-for-wordpress/5163957
has added the possibility to define a target element to apply the parallax to. The selector works just like jQuery selector.